# Bind to HierarchicalDataTemplate DataContext from nested DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchical-data

I have my treeview with 2 level nested levels.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Project.Tables}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TableModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ColumnModel}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

My binding source with tables:

```
public class ProjectModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private BindableCollection<TableModel> _tables;

    public BindableCollection<TableModel> Tables
    {
        get { return _tables; }
        set
        {
            if (_tables != value)
            {
                _tables = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TableModel
{
    public BindableCollection<ColumnModel> Columns { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

I tried to use next binding:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type projectModels:ColumnModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=DataContext.IsSelected }" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource GreyBrush3}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}">
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Inside DataTemplate I want to have binding to DataContext of HierarchicalDataTemplate. I already tried different AncestorLevels and it did not work, any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever resolve this?